# How to change the number of post in the Blog and include Pagination

Tags: wordpress

I have made a blog using WordPress. The Homepage is set to Latest articles as shown below:

[image]

There are 19 posts on my blog, and when I open the blog I see the most recent 10 posts on the [home page](https://blog.shopless.co.nz/):

1. Why am I only seeing 10 post, where I have set the number of posts
   to be 12?
2. How can I display the paginations? I thought it should display by default?

I am using Astra Theme.

### Update

The reason I am seeing 10 post, is that I have chosen to show a `static page` called `Latest articles`... If I had chosen `Your latest posts` options then the setting should have works.

Now in the *Latest articles* page, I have inserted a block called Latest Posts:

[image]

I can to change the `Number of items` in the Latest Posts settings:

[image]

**However I still don't know how to add a pagination here?**

Comment: I suppose your Astra theme settings override this basic Wordpress setting. Or, you have two posts that Astra has categorized as something like a "featured" post or special type of post that shows up on the front page, but are maybe excluded from the main blog feed itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pagination should be included in the template for the index, but not usually pages.

Looking at the code for the Astra theme, the [index.php](https://themes.trac.wordpress.org/browser/astra/3.6.8/index.php) file includes the function to `astra_pagination()`, whereas the [page.php](https://themes.trac.wordpress.org/browser/astra/3.6.8/page.php) template does not.

Because you are setting it to a page, there won't be any pagination by default (you should be using the setting 'Your latest posts' rather than the page you've selected - this will then start using the index.php file which usually contains pagination).

If your theme doesn't give the display you need when using 'Your latest posts', then I would suggest creating a child theme, and creating an override for the index.php file that does what you need to do (which would be calling `astra_pagination()` after your main content.